# ReactJS many tables from one data array/json/request from DB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I'm new with React and I like to built the same tables on my frontage with such data

Example data from MongoDB:

```
{name:"flower1", price: 5, quantity: 34, color:"red"}
{name:"flower2", price: 4, quantity: 57, color:"blue"}
{name:"flower3", price: 6, quantity: 56, color:"white"}
{name:"flower4", price: 6, quantity: 56, color:"red"}
{name:"flower5", price: 8, quantity: 56, color:"blue"}
```

but with only one `type` in every table

Table structure:

```
{table_name_by_color_from_DB}
Name | Price | Quantity
```

For example I have 3 different colors, so it should be three tables. I could easily create tables in React, but each time when I want to create table, I should request data from Mongo. If I have 10 colors I should create 10 tables, and I'm afraid that it will be too much requests. So what's the best practice to do so? Can I just request Mongo once and then separate data from response for each table by color with .map? Could someone provide advice or a code-snippet for that?

Comment: Don't put a burden on reactjs. Instead get table data in a structured format from nodejs.  Your API should provide a separate array for each color and show table for each array. What you think

Comment: yeah, you right, at first I thought about it, but it's a bit more complicated than that. It's about 10+ "colors" and I should request DB from another collection to make receive result data for creating table. So it's will be already [color x 2] request to DB, but the key problem here, that I write a lot of data (almost realtime) and it's a bit loaded. But, as for now, I get X requests via API (by colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the groupBy helper from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy)

```
groupBy(data, 'color')
```

will restructure your data into

```
{
    red: [
        {name:"flower1", price: 5, quantity: 34, color:"red"},
        {name:"flower4", price: 6, quantity: 56, color:"red"}
    ],
    blue: [
        {name:"flower2", price: 4, quantity: 57, color:"blue"},
        {name:"flower5", price: 8, quantity: 56, color:"blue"}
    ],
    white: [
        {name:"flower3", price: 6, quantity: 56, color:"white"}
    ]
}
```

and you can map that into your Table Component

```
{
   Object.keys(data).map(color => (
       <TableComponent data={data[color]} />
   ))
}
```